# terraform plan "Reference to undeclared resource" error

Tags: terraform

I use terraformer to import AWS ALB resources.
But when I try to run terraform plan, this error happened.

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│ 
│   on outputs.tf line 914, in output "output_name":
│  914:   value = aws_lb_target_group_attachment.attachment_name.id
│ 
│ A managed resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment"
│ "attachment_name"
│ has not been declared in the root module.
```

I find the {resource_type} {resource_name} in my local

```
        {
          "mode": "managed",
          "type": "aws_lb_target_group_attachment",
          "name": "attachment_name",
          "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws\"]",
```

I don't know why outputs.tf can't reference local resource.

Comment: Please add code showing definition of your `aws_lb_target_group_attachment.attachment_name` and the outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I do not use any module and all files in the same path.
I define aws_lb_target_group_attachment as 

`resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "attachment_name" {
  target_group_arn = "target_group_arn"
  target_id        = "IP"
}`
and the output likes

`output "aws_lb_target_group_attachment_attachment_name" {
  value = aws_lb_target_group_attachment.attachment_name.id
}`